# Get all file names in src folder, codenameone project

Tags: codenameone

Is there a way to get all the file names in the src folder in a codenameone project (usually next to the theme.res file)?

I tried using:

```
    try {
        Resources theme = Resources.openLayered("/theme");
        return theme.getImageResourceNames();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However, this seems to only return the resource images within the .res file itself. I also tried

```
Storage.getInstance().listEntries();
```

and

```
FileSystemStorage.getInstance().listFiles(FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath());
```

Though these seem to return the storage on the device, not that which is embedded in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No and you probably shouldn't do that. The "files" there are translated to platform native representation which means they will not act in a portable way like they would in the simulator and you might run into weird "on-device" issues.

You can create a list of files in a text file during build and save it there then use that as a reference but I'd rethink that idea. If you would ask a question describing what you are trying to achieve then I might be able to offer a better approach e.g. we use TAR to package the HTML files in the html directory so we can get a device portable web browsing experience.

Comment: Someone else doing images would drop images in that folder. The program is built in such a way that all images dropped there are viable for use. My idea was to build up a list on startup.

The text file does seem viable, considering I have implemented native code to deal with image processing. As long as the byte array from the file remains the same.

Am I correct in saying that image files themselves (.png and .gif images) won't be affected when things are translated to native representations?

Comment: The image files won't be affected. However, it sounds like you are building a tool to quickly customize apps. If you just place image resources they might look pixelated or too big on the various devices as on-device-scaling isn't very good. I have no idea why you need native code for image processing though. Personally I would use a resource file which you can generate from command line and have multi-images in it.